# Calling Java Main method from static block

Tags: java, static

I am curious to know how JVM sees below code

```
public class StrTest {
    static int i=10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(++i);
    }
    static{
        String[] args = new String[10];
        main(args);
        System.out.println(++i);
        StrTest test = new StrTest();
        test.main(args);
    }
}
```

is there any design patter in any framework using these kind of calling where application in instantiated from the static block or something before main.

edited after a new finding

```
public class StrTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println("in main");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("in static block");
        String[] args = new String[10];
        main(args);
        new StrTest().main(args);;
    }
    static int i = 10;

}
```

this is printing

```
in static block
1
in main
2
in main
11
in main
```

but

```
public class StrTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println("in main");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println(++i);//this line here is giving error Cannot 
                                //reference a field before it is defined
        System.out.println("in static block");
        String[] args = new String[10];
        main(args);
        new StrTest().main(args);;
    }
    static int i = 10;

}
```

why then in first case it's initializing i to 0;

Comment: what exactly do you mean? you can call main, but main won't run. also: calling a static method on an instance?

Comment: Static block runs during class loading. Not sure you can run main method. I am only curious about why anyone would need that ?

Comment: This program runs. However, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I was able to print "i" 4 times so it means the main was called from there. I just wanted to know if there could be anything based on this pattern

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The `static` block gets executed when the class gets loaded, and the class gets loaded because it contains the `main` method. You're going around in circles. Can you call `main` from a `static` block or from another method? Sure. Should you? No.

Comment: true that. I am trying new things in java so anything I don't find I ask. Thanks all

Comment: You might want to spend some more time at the [help] to learn how / what to ask. It is a bad idea for example to ask more than *one* thing in a question. The question "why is this happening" is completely separate from "is this is a commonly known pattern". And please note: the first part about "how exactly this works in detail" won't get you positive feedback - that is really basic knowledge that you can A) test yourself and B) is documented in many existing questions/answers and well, any good book or tutorial. Dont expect us to explain things that you can find with 10 minutes of research.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. And why? Because it is a **bad** idea.

There are few occasions where *static* init blocks are useful - but they are definitely not a mean to trigger a complete `main()` and God knows what else!

You see: these blocks get executed most likely at *load* time. This means that you have almost **no** control when exactly that happens. And you don't want to base complex behavior to start at some *random* point in time!

Beyond that: you are really *careful* about using `static` in the first place. It looks like nice and convenient to the newbie programmer, but rest assured: in the real world, you are extremely cautious about using it. Because it directly *couples* things together (and it *kills* polymorphism - thereby greatly diminishing the value of "OOP"). And you are even more careful about using `static` init blocks. Acceptable use cases could be things like:

```
public static final Map<Foo, Bar> SOME_KEYS = new HashMap<>();
static {
  SOME_KEYS.put(someFoo, someBar);
  SOME_KEYS.put(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar);
...
```

In other words: you only use it to actually **initialize** variables, or more precise: *constants*.

Comment: cat : did u -1 this question?

Comment: @SagarKharab Your question isn't exactly great, but rest assured: when I deem a question worth close/downvoting, then I do exactly that. The other way round: I will not downvote a question that I intend to answer. But as said: your question is of "questionable quality".

Comment: Thanks but actually I just was sitting and checking if this happens and thought if any pattern may be based on this. I am not sure why someone would down vote this curious thing. I am really not an expert in java but learning stuff. Anyway thanks

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

GhostCat clearly explained why you should not do it. I would add that it is not idiomatic and would make future code maintenance harder.

Now what *technically* happens seen from the JVM:

- loads the executable jar file
- find the class `StrTest` as the *booting* class containing a static main
- the class loader loads the class and do the static initialization:

  - initializes the static variable i
  - executes the static init block:
  - calls `StrTest.main` because of the `main()` line

    - increases and print i
  - increases and print i
  - calls `StrTest.main` because of the `test.main()` line, because `test` is a `StrTest` object

    - increases and print i
- all that has happened before the JVM has called main as part of the program startup!...
- The JVM normally calls `StrTest.main` with the actual command line arguments as parameter

  - increases and print i

It could work here because you have no serious operation in main, but the result is that main was called several times. In a normal program, that could lead to catastrophic results, just think of a program that consumes an input file to erase and produce an output file: on second iteration it will erase its output file but has no input any more...

What you should have learned from that:

- the class containing `main` is still a normal Java class and supports all standard Java operations
- the `main` method is a normal static method and *could* be used as such
- you should never to that in normal code

---

As per edit of the question, *The Java Language Specification Java SE 8 edition* says:

> The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order,

As in the edited code the initialization of the static variable occurs *after* the static bloc, the static bloc is executed with a default value of 0 for i and only then `i` takes the value `10`. Here again, please do not play with that in real code...

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: Nice addendum ;-)

Comment: Thanks....I am sorry if I pissed u off with initial question

Comment: @SagarKharab Mind your language ;-) ... and please note: no feedback that you receive here is meant to be personal. Take it as *feedback* that helps you to improve the quality of the content you put up here.

Comment: sure Ghostcat. Thanks a lot :)